# How can I speed up this slow simple query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `game` 
WHERE (hometeam=29 OR awayteam=29) 
  AND `sportid`=1 
  AND`date` BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND deleted=0
```

This simple query takes 0.5-1.1 seconds (without caching). The table holes 1.6M rows, so I think it should be much faster (<0.1 second). In the explain below, it shows it's searching through half of the table. You can see I've tried various index variations with no luck, it always wants to use the sportid index.

```
id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                            | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | game  | ref  | date,hometeam,awayteam,sportid,deleted,sportid_2,sportid_3,sportid_4,sportid_5,sportid_6 | sportid | 1       | const | 800368 | Using where
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE game

```
CREATE TABLE `game` (
 `gameid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sportid` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `hometeam` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `awayteam` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `homescore` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `awayscore` tinyint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `stadiumid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `neutral` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `time` time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
 `confid` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `srs-predict` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `srs-teamid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `crs-predict` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `crs-teamid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `winner` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `forfeit` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `playoff` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H1` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H2` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H3` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H4` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H5` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H6` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H7` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `H8` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A1` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A2` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A3` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A4` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A5` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A6` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A7` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `A8` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `reportedby` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastscandate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`gameid`),
 KEY `winner` (`winner`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `hometeam` (`hometeam`),
 KEY `awayteam` (`awayteam`),
 KEY `sportid` (`sportid`),
 KEY `lastscandate` (`lastscandate`),
 KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
 KEY `sportid_2` (`sportid`,`awayteam`,`date`),
 KEY `sportid_3` (`sportid`,`hometeam`,`date`),
 KEY `sportid_4` (`sportid`,`awayteam`,`date`,`deleted`),
 KEY `sportid_5` (`sportid`,`hometeam`,`date`,`deleted`),
 KEY `sportid_6` (`sportid`,`hometeam`,`awayteam`,`date`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1969140 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Pleas read up on [why you shouldn't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (especially with date/time/timestamp values in SQL Server, but applies elsewhere).  Among other things, that date/time value should be combined as a timestamp.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for the warning, but it doesn't apply in this instance because my data is really in August-May, so there's no risk of ever being cutoff wrongly by `BETWEEN`. But I appreciate the knowledge so it doesn't affect my future cases.

Comment: @MECU: The advice is good. It doesn't affect you because your column is of `DATE` datatype. If the datatype was `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` (or if you change it later) it would affect you. But if your condition was `date >= '2012-07-01' AND date < '2013-07-01'` (notice the +1 day) instead of the `BETWEEN` it would work with any of these datatypes. It's also slightly easier to construct the condition (no need to remember which months have 30 and which 31 days, not to mention which Februaries have 28 and which 29.)

Comment: @ypercube I understand and agree the advice is good. I appreciate the extra explanation as well and see your point about how to better construct the query. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE game
  ADD INDEX deleted_sportid_hometeam_date_IX          -- choose names
    (deleted, sportid, hometeam, date), 
  ADD INDEX deleted_sportid_awayteam_date_IX          -- for the indexes
    (deleted, sportid, awayteam, date)  ;
```

and then running this version:

```
SELECT * FROM game 
WHERE hometeam = 29
  AND sportid = 1 
  AND date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND deleted = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM game
WHERE awayteam = 29 
  AND sportid = 1 
  AND date BETWEEN '2012-07-01' AND '2013-06-30'
  AND deleted = 0 ;
```

---

You can still try your original query after having added the 2 indexes and the efficiency will probably be improved (but not much, depends on the selectivity of the `deleted - sportid` combination.) But I don't think the optimizer is smart enough to understand that this (rewriting) is equivalent to that (original query) and that it could use both indexes, one for the 1st and the other for the 2nd part, so you will only have a small efficiency gain.

So, the "why is it faster this way" has mainly to do with the `OR` condition and with the limited ability of the optimizer to rewrite queries in equivalent forms. This rewriting for example would never be produced anyway by an automated optimizer (because I assumed that `hometeam` and `awayteam` are never the same, which the optimizer cannot guess.) If home team and away team could be the same, then we'd have to use `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`).

B-tree indexes are super-good for conditions with `AND`, only. When there are `ORs` or otherwise complicated conditions, they are not so good. Occasionally - like in this case - there is a way to rewrite a query so it has only `ANDs`. The last part of the execution (the `UNION ALL`) can be executed in MySQL by running the two subqueries one after the other and showing all results from both so there is no calculations or delay there.

Comment: Wow! Less than 0.002 seconds. Amazing! My question is why is it faster to select twice and union than my simple OR?

Comment: I'd try putting `date` first as supposedly most selective column.

Comment: @a1ex07 No, because of the range condition on the date column. It's better at the last place of the index.

Comment: @ypercube : good point(+), you may be right in the context of this particular query; I didn't pay attention to it while reading the question first time.

Comment: @ypercube The old OR query is still not any faster with the new indexes. You were correct to assume hometeam and awayteam will never be the same. Thank you very much for your help and the extra mile with the why explanation.